# I have ACF installed and activated, but can't use them to select certain WP pages based on custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to query WP pages and display their titles based on ACF custom field data.
My ACF field is promotion_url, and the needed value is 3.

This is the code I use:

```
    <?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'promotion_url',
            'value' => '3',
        )
    )
); $my_query = new WP_Query($args)?> <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Can someone please help me, what am I doing wrong?

If i delete this part, I get all the pages's titles displayed without any problems.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'promotion_url',
        'value' => '3',
    )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you did not set value of 'compare' in array: Please try:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'promotion_url',
        'value' => '3',
        'compare'   => '=',
    )
)
```

You could view document to query with ACF in [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/)